# Changing the value of a column in a Pandas Dataframe based on another column containing boolean values (Pycharm weak warning)

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, warnings

I have a Pandas Dataframe and I would like to change the value in a column if the boolean value in another column is True.

I have code that works but PyCharm is giving me a weak warning about using double quotes to compare the column value with the boolean value.

```
df.loc[df["boolColumn"] == True, "responseColumn"] = "Yes"
```

I get a weak warning saying:

```
PEP 8: E712 comparison to True should be 'if cond is True:' or 'if cond:'
```

I changed the condition to

```
df.loc[df["boolColumn"] is True, "responseColumn"] = "Yes"
```

and this got rid of the warnings in Pycharm but when I run the code I get an error saying:

```
KeyError: 'cannot use a single bool to index into setitem'
```

I know my original code works but I was wondering if the way I'm coding is incorrect and there is a correct way to do what I want.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `==` operator by [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) method:

```
df.loc[df["boolColumn"].eq(True), "responseColumn"] = "Yes"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked like a 'charm'.  Sorry I couldn't pass a bad pun.  But seriously, thank you for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your original code would work, but to simplify it (and get rid of the warning), you can use:

```
df.loc[df["boolColumn"], "responseColumn"] = "Yes"
```

This uses the boolean column directly as the index, rather than comparing to "True".

Comment: Ahh, good point.  I'm all for more efficient code.  That's my main problem right now, I can generally find a way of doing what I want but it's usually not the best or most efficient way of doing it.